# How to add multiple div element below other div on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox, laravel-blade

I am trying to generate a div with its contents below a particular div . On clicking add button, the same div should display below the current div.
I have a list of checkboxes generated from a loop. I have another checkbox which is outside the loop labeled as 'Other' . On clicking the 'Other' checkbox, it should display a product and volume textbox which is placed in a div. On clicking the add button, this div with the textboxes should display again below the current div. Whenever I click the add button, the div should be generated below the current div. How to do so?

What I have tried is

```
 <div class="container">
                               @foreach($res as $product)
                               <div class="form-group row">
                                   <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
                                <label for="recipient-name{{$product->id}}" class="col-form-label">
                                    <input type="checkbox"  class="chooseProduct" id="recipient-name{{$product->id}}" name="pname[]" data-id="{{$product->id}}"  value="{{$product->product}}" onchange="enableVolume(this);" >{{$product->product}}</label>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="col-sm-6">
                                       <label for="volume{{$product->id}}">    <input type="number" id="volume{{$product->id}}" class="form-control" name="volume[]" placeholder="Volume" min="0"  step="0.01"  disabled> </label>
                               </div>
                               </div>
                               
                               @endforeach
                               <div class="form-group row">
                                   
                                   <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
                                <label for="recipient-name_o" class="col-form-label">
                                     <input type="checkbox"  class="chooseProduct" id="recipient-name_o" name="other_product" data-id="o_id"  value="" onchange="otherOption(this);" >Other</label>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <!--<label for="volume_o">    <input type="number" id="volume_o" class="form-control" name="volumeo_id" placeholder="Volume" min="0"  step="0.01"  disabled> </label>
                           -->  </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class="form-group row" id="otherCheck">
                                   <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
                                <label for="text-o" class="col-form-label">
                                    <input type="text"  class="chooseProduct form-control" id="text-o" name="text-o" data-id="text-o" placeholder="Product Name" value=""  ></label>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="col-sm-6">
                                       <label for="volume_o">    <input type="number" id="volumetext-o" class="form-control" name="volumeo_id" placeholder="Volume" min="0"  step="0.01"> </label>
                            </div>
                                   <button class='btn btn-primary' id='add_btn' onclick="addDiv();" >Add</button>
                               </div>
                               @if(count($pdf_data)>0)
                               <div class="form-group row">
                                   <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
                                <label for="prescription" class="col-form-label">
                                     <input type="checkbox"  class="chooseProduct" id="prescription" name="prescription" data-id="prescription"  value='Agronomist Prescription' onchange="enableVolume(this);" >Most Recent Agronomist Prescription</label>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <label for="volume_pres">    <input type="number" id="volumeprescription" class="form-control" name="volume_pres" placeholder="Volume" min="0"  step="0.01"  disabled> </label>
                             </div>
                               </div>
                               <div id='append'></div>
                               @endif
                          </div>
```

My output

[image: Output]

Expected Output should generate textbox below current div . On clicking add button again, another two textboxes should generate again, and so on. How to do so?

Comment: You basically want a todo list app? There are many tutorials online for this, will need JavaScript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ! Bloated code with HTML divs and class attributes. + Precise if you want this solution managed by the backend or JS. And most importantly what did you try ?